# I keep getting this Error when writing my Django code: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'profile'

Tags: django, django-views

def edit(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.profile)

    if form.is_valid():

        form.save()

        return redirect(reverse('/profile'))

else:

    form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.profile)

    args = {'form': form}
```

This is my code for the view and it always gives me an error when I go to this URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access your user by using `request.user` object and not `request.profile`.

Comment: I tried that and it didnt work it says this is the error:form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.profile)

Comment: are you extending user model? Can you paste your model

Comment: class Profile(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=' ', blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

Comment: It looks like your request object is not having profile attribute. Try accessing using `request.user` or debug request object for parameters

Answer (score -1):

Use the below line for redirect, make sure app_name is set in urls.py for your app

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('your_app_name:url_name'))
```

Comment: this didn't work the method is still get and I need it to be POST